# how to pass MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES as enviroment directivei in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose, mercure

the new (0.11) mercure configuration grouped all extra directive into a single environment variable.
I'm trying to set it via docker-compose.yml but I don't know if it's possible:

```
environment:   
  MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: /docker/public.pem  
  MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: /docker/public.pem  
  MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG: RS256   MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG: RS256  
  MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES:
     anonymous: 0
     demo: 0
     write_timeout: 15m
```

This block fails with .environment.MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES contains {"anonymous": 0, "demo": 0,... }  which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null

how do I pass all the directive via docker-compose to mercure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
environment:   
  MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: /docker/public.pem  
  MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: /docker/public.pem  
  MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG: RS256   
  MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG: RS256  
  MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: |
     anonymous 0 
     demo 0
     write_timeout 15m
```

So the `MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES` are interpreted long string